# How to Upload Audio/Videos using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm working on Audio/Video upload and Task. Can somebody help me show to achieve this functionality in Angular JS?

Comment: well i created an File tag, and wrote script like this.  $scope.add = function(){
  var f = document.getElementById('file').files[0],
      r = new FileReader();
  r.onloadend = function(e){
    var data = e.target.result;
    //send you binary data via $http or $resource or do anything else with it
  }
  r.readAsBinaryString(f);
}  But i can't help me

Comment: You might find [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) library helpful.

Answer (score 0):

We would need more details, what hae you tried, what type of backend (REST, SOAP, Web Service in general) you are using, in which language...

I did it with a Java RESTful server by, probably, not the smarter solution.

```
$scope.uploadVideo = function(){

    // Obtaining the selected file. In case of many, the others will be from the position 1 of the array
    var f = document.getElementById("videoInput").files[0];
    console.log("====================>SIZE: "+f.size);
    var name = f.name;

    //Getting the file name and its extension

    }

    //Loading the file and passing the callback as a parameter
    loadFile(f, function(data){
        // The file consist on its name and bytes
        var file={
            name:name,
            data:data
        }
        //Sending the video
        servicioRest.postFile(file)
        .then(function(){
            //Whatever

        })
        .catch(function(err){
            console.log("ERROR");
            alert("ERROR: "+err);
        });
    });        
};

//---------------------------------------------------- UTILS ----------------------------------------------

function loadFile(source, callBack){;
    var r = new FileReader();

    //Event that will be triggered when FileReader finish reading the file
    r.onloadend = function(e){
        var data = e.target.result;
        // some chars cannot be sent through http requests. So we encode them in base64 to ensure we send the correct bytes
        data=btoa(data);    
        console.log(data.length);
        callBack(data);
    //send you binary data via $http or $resource or do anything else with it
    }

    //Reading the file. When it ends, the event "onloadend", previously declared, will be triggered
    r.readAsBinaryString(source);
}
```

Then, in the server, I decoded the bytes and create a file with them and that bytes... or save them in the database.. Whatever you want.

But I insist, we need more details to answer you correctly. It's impossible, at list for me, to answer you correctly with only that information